# Unable to import lambda_handler in AWS Lambda

Tags: pandas, aws-lambda

I am trying to run pandas code in AWS Lamdba by following https://medium.com/@korniichuk/lambda-with-pandas-fd81aa2ff25e.

After zipping the folder and running the lambda code below was my error.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function'"
}
```

So thought to try a simple code without any libaries. Once I zipped and uploaded the folder I found this..

[image]

As the zip size is small, I can move the file inside inline-editor. But it's not possible for larger zip folder once I import all my libs in the zip.

How can I zip the folders properly and uploading it?

Does the lambda function name and zip file name should be same?

Answer (score 0):

Put the `lambda_function.py` in the root of the directory. Your file is inside a directory called `to`.

Your folder view should look something like

[image]

Comment: I have already mentioned that. I know my file is in 'to' folder and my lambda function name is 'Testing' . so when uploaded the zip file why the Testing folder comes?

Comment: Um because you're zipping that folder? Zip from the folder where your lambda_function.py file is.